# Why is a hashmap slower when I edit it to be able to look up pointers as keys?

Tags: c++, performance, hashmap, hashtable

Here's a hashmap which I tried to make faster for something:
https://github.com/martinus/robin-hood-hashing/blob/master/src/include/robin_hood.h

I tried to make lookups faster by making it so it could use `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>` keys and look up keys by raw pointers, and I did this by including cwchar on line 51, and adding the code from lines 770-809, lines 1726-1778, and lines 2628-2630:
https://pastebin.com/zbhxEj7B

```cpp
    // lines 770-809
    template <class T>
    struct ptr_comparer
    {
        bool operator() (const std::unique_ptr<T[]>& arr1, const std::unique_ptr<T[]>& arr2) const
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            return std::wcscmp(arr1.get(), arr2.get()) == 0;
#else
            return std::strcmp(arr1.get(), arr2.get()) == 0;
#endif
        }

        bool operator() (const std::unique_ptr<T[]>& arr1, const T* arr2) const
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            return std::wcscmp(arr1.get(), arr2) == 0;
#else
            return std::strcmp(arr1.get(), arr2) == 0;
#endif
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct ptr_hasher
    {
        size_t operator()(std::unique_ptr<T[]> const& arr) const noexcept
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            return hash_bytes(arr.get(), sizeof(T) * (std::wcslen(arr.get()) + 1));
#else
            return hash_bytes(arr.get(), sizeof(T) * (std::strlen(arr.get()) + 1));
#endif
        }

        // used with findWithSize
        size_t operator()(const T* arr, int size) const noexcept
        {
            return hash_bytes(arr, sizeof(T) * size);
        }
    };
```

```cpp
                // lines 1726-1778
                // same as keyToIdx, but takes size as argument and calls WHash::operator() with size argument
                void keyToIdxWithSize(const char_type* key, size_t* idx, InfoType* info, int size) const {
                    // In addition to whatever hash is used, add another mul & shift so we get better hashing.
                    // This serves as a bad hash prevention, if the given data is
                    // badly mixed.

                    auto h = static_cast<uint64_t>(WHash::operator()(key, size));

                    h *= mHashMultiplier;
                    h ^= h >> 33U;

                    // the lower InitialInfoNumBits are reserved for info.
                    *info = mInfoInc + static_cast<InfoType>((h & InfoMask) >> mInfoHashShift);
                    *idx = (static_cast<size_t>(h) >> InitialInfoNumBits) & mMask;
                }

                // same as findIdx, but takes size as argument and calls keyToIdxWithSize
                ROBIN_HOOD(NODISCARD)
                    size_t findIdxWithSize(const char_type* arr, int size) const
                {
                    size_t idx{};
                    InfoType info{};
                    keyToIdxWithSize(arr, &idx, &info, size);

                    do {
                        // unrolling this twice gives a bit of a speedup. More unrolling did not help.
                        if (info == mInfo[idx] &&
                            ROBIN_HOOD_LIKELY(WKeyEqual::operator()(mKeyVals[idx].getFirst(), arr))) {
                            return idx;
                        }
                        next(&info, &idx);
                        if (info == mInfo[idx] &&
                            ROBIN_HOOD_LIKELY(WKeyEqual::operator()(mKeyVals[idx].getFirst(), arr))) {
                            return idx;
                        }
                        next(&info, &idx);
                    } while (info <= mInfo[idx]);

                    // nothing found!
                    return mMask == 0 ? 0
                        : static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(
                            mKeyVals, reinterpret_cast_no_cast_align_warning<Node*>(mInfo)));
                }

                // same as iterator find(const key_type& key), but takes size as argument and calls findIdxWithSize
                // size passed as int because the c string won't be larger than INT_MAX
                iterator findWithSize(const char_type* arr, int size)
                {
                    ROBIN_HOOD_TRACE(this)
                        const size_t idx = findIdxWithSize(arr, size);
                    return iterator{ mKeyVals + idx, mInfo + idx };
                }
```

```cpp
    // lines 2628-2630
    template <typename Key, typename T, typename Hash = ptr_hasher<char_type>,
        typename KeyEqual = ptr_comparer<char_type>, size_t MaxLoadFactor100 = 80>
        using ptr_map = detail::Table<false, MaxLoadFactor100, Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual>;
```

The problem is that this ends up being about 100 nanoseconds slower than just using `std::wstring_view` keys. Why is it so much slower? In the program I'm using this for, I assumed it would be faster because I'm doing basically the same thing except for needing to make a `std::wstring_view` object from a `wchar_t` pointer. But it's slower in spite of that.

This is the code I'm using to check the speed:

```cpp
static NTSTATUS WINAPI NtCreateFileHook(
    PHANDLE            FileHandle,
    ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
    POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK   IoStatusBlock,
    PLARGE_INTEGER     AllocationSize,
    ULONG              FileAttributes,
    ULONG              ShareAccess,
    ULONG              CreateDisposition,
    ULONG              CreateOptions,
    PVOID              EaBuffer,
    ULONG              EaLength)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    wchar_t* file_path = (wchar_t*)(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer);
    wchar_t* file_name = file_path + ((ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Length) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    int file_name_size = 0; // will always increase to at least 0 due to there always being a null terminator
    for (; file_name >= file_path && *file_name != L'\\'; file_name--, file_name_size++) {}
    robin_hood::ptr_map<std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>, std::unique_ptr<int[]>>::iterator idk_iter = idk.findWithSize(file_name + 1, file_name_size);
    if (idk_iter != idk.end()) // this will be false almost always, and times when it's true aren't counted
    {
        delay_file(idk, idk_iter->second, delay_array_mutex);
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
    long long int n = duration.count();
    char buf[21] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%llu\n", n);
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), f);
    return NtCreateFile(
        FileHandle,
        DesiredAccess,
        ObjectAttributes,
        IoStatusBlock,
        AllocationSize,
        FileAttributes,
        ShareAccess,
        CreateDisposition,
        CreateOptions,
        EaBuffer,
        EaLength
    );
}
```

This version takes about 550 nanoseconds on average, but if I instead don't edit the hashmap at all, and use `std::wstring_view` keys and create a `std::wstring_view` object in the function to pass to the hashmap, it only takes about 450 nanoseconds on average. Why is that?

I compiled on Windows 10 in MSVC with O2 optimization.

UPDATE: I still don't know why it's slower. Someone suggested it could be because `std::wstring_view` objects will compare lengths when using `operator==`. I was pretty sure this wouldn't matter, but I tested it anyways by storing the size in the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of the `wchar_t` strings and changing lines 770-809 to this:

```cpp
    template <class T>
    struct ptr_comparer
    {
        bool operator() (const std::unique_ptr<T[]>& arr1, const std::unique_ptr<T[]>& arr2) const
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            return std::wcscmp(arr1.get() + (sizeof(int) / sizeof(T)), arr2.get() + (sizeof(int) / sizeof(T))) == 0;
#else
            return std::strcmp(arr1.get() + (sizeof(int) / sizeof(T)), arr2.get() + (sizeof(int) / sizeof(T))) == 0;
#endif
        }

        bool operator() (const std::unique_ptr<T[]>& arr1, const T* arr2, int arr2size) const
        {
            T* arr1ptr = arr1.get();
            int n = 0;
            std::memcpy(&n, arr1ptr, sizeof(int));
            arr1ptr += sizeof(int) / sizeof(T);
#ifdef _WIN32
            return n == arr2size && std::wcscmp(arr1ptr, arr2) == 0;
#else
            return n == arr2size && std::strcmp(arr1ptr, arr2) == 0;
#endif
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct ptr_hasher
    {
        size_t operator()(std::unique_ptr<T[]> const& arr) const noexcept
        {
            T* arrptr = arr.get() + (sizeof(int) / sizeof(T));
#ifdef _WIN32
            return hash_bytes(arrptr, sizeof(T) * (std::wcslen(arrptr) + 1));
#else
            return hash_bytes(arrptr, sizeof(T) * (std::strlen(arrptr) + 1));
#endif
    }

        // used with findWithSize
        size_t operator()(const T* arr, int size) const noexcept
        {
            return hash_bytes(arr, sizeof(T) * size);
        }
    };
```

The results are no different, it's still about 550 nanoseconds.

UPDATE 2: I figured out that if I call `hash_bytes` in `keyToIdx` instead of calling `WHash::operator()`, it makes it slower by about 100ns. Why, and how do I fix that so I can put `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>` in the hashmap without that speed loss?

Comment: Also, when it does enter this if-block in the bottom block of code, I don't count that time when checking what the average is:

`if (idk_iter != idk.end())`

So what happens in the `delay_file` function doesn't matter.

Comment: One difference is that `string_view`'s operator== compares the string sizes before comparing the characters.  No need to call `wcscmp` if the strings are not the same length.

Comment: Shouldn't that make wstring_view slower unless the strings are the same for a significant length at their starts?

Comment: @my_first_c_program Where are the settings you used to compile your code?  We do not know if you are compiling with optimizations turned on.  We don't even know what compiler and version of the compiler you're using.  All of these things are important when asking "why is this code slow/fast?"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I compiled on Windows 10 in MSVC with O2 optimization

Comment: Unrelated note: Do not use `high_resolution_clock::now()`. It has different implementations in various compilers so will make your program harder to port to other platforms. Use `steady_clock::now()` for durations and measurement.

Comment: @my_first_c_program - About sizes: `string_view` holds the size of the string, so comparing lengths is just a single compare. Same for the hashing - no calls to  `wcslen` as the length is already known.

Comment: @BoP It shouldn't need to use wcslen for lookups because I already know the length by the time I try look up the pointer.